# Prevent values going outside a specified range

Tags: java, math, max, min

```
private int currentSpeed;
private static final int MAXIMUM_SPEED = 100;
private int heading;

int speedUp(int increaseBy) {

    currentSpeed += increaseBy;

    return currentSpeed;
}

int slowDown(int decreaseBy) {

    currentSpeed -= decreaseBy;

    return currentSpeed;
}
```

How can i prevent the value `currentSpeed` from exceeding the `MAXIMUM_VALUE` variable in the speedUp method, and also from dropping below 0 in the `slowDown` method without using an if statement. I believe using `Math.min` & `Math.max`  would work, but i'm unsure how to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Math.max` and `Math.min` as below:

```
int speedUp(int increaseBy) {
    currentSpeed = Math.min(currentSpeed + increaseBy,MAXIMUM_SPEED);
    return currentSpeed;
}

int slowDown(int decreaseBy) {
    currentSpeed = Math.max(currentSpeed - decreaseBy,0);
    return currentSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to it using [ternary operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018)

```
int speedUp(int increaseBy) {
    currentSpeed = currentSpeed + increaseBy < MAXIMUM_SPEED ? currentSpeed += increaseBy : MAXIMUM_SPEED;
    return currentSpeed;
}

int slowDown(int decreaseBy) {
    currentSpeed = currentSpeed - decreaseBy > 0 ? currentSpeed -= decreaseBy : 0;
    return currentSpeed;
}
```

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - Won't work here. It should be `MAXIMUM_SPEED`.